# Соединение Jenkins и GitLab: Client error: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Tags: gitlab, jenkins

Как настроить связь GitLab и Jenkins? В Gitlab host URL ссылка на приватную группу,  в GitLab API token - персональный токен доступа члена группы (Maintainer) с галкой api. Но авторизации нет, в чем может быть проблема? [image: Скрин из глобальных конфигураций]

Если в Gitlab host URL ввести просто https://gitlab.com/ то TestConnection выдает Success, однако при создании Item

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://gitlab.com/qa_InSAT/temprepos.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. 
>   Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. 
>   remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/qa_InSAT/temprepos.git/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не нашел нормального ответа на вопрос. Проблему обошел войдя в учетную запись GitLab в Windows версии гита. Видимо это применилось для любой попытки доступа к репозиториям пользователя